# how do you prompt the user with a toast-like message in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want the user to confirm an action by showing them a dialogue with a message and "yes" or "no" buttons. How can I make that appear, and perform actions based on the button they pick?

Thanks, AlertDialog looks like what I'm looking for. But, there's an error where it says `"AlertDialog.Builder(this);"` that tells me, `"The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"` –

Comment: Obviously ... `System.err.println("Do you like toast?");`  :-)

Answer (score 4):

As shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) :

```
private static final int DIALOG = 1;
```

to show the dialog call

```
showDialog(DIALOG);
```

override onCreateDialog, check with a switch for the dialog ID and insert

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure about this?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // whatever if YES
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // whetever if NO
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is an `AlertDialog`. Using the example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog), you can easily create a Yes/No dialog that will look something along the lines of:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's simple as below

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Info")
            .setMessage("hello")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked                 
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
                }
            })
            .show();
```